# Understanding scope in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm pretty new to angular, so I hope this question isn't too basic. I'm trying to run a function in angular, but I seem to have an issue with the scope of my variables. This is what it looks like:

```
export class Skulder14q1Component {

  button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
  button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
  button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
  button4 = document.getElementById('button4');
  showallbutton = document.getElementById('showallbutton');

  onShowAllOptions() {
    this.button1.classList.toggle('hide');
    this.button2.classList.toggle('hide');
    this.button3.classList.toggle('hide');
    this.button4.classList.toggle('hide');
    this.showallbutton.classList.add('hide');
  }
```

Now the function is run by the press of a button, but when pressing the button, the console log returns this:

```
> Skulder14q1Component.html:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at Skulder14q1Component.onShowAllOptions (skulder14q1.component.ts:28)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (Skulder14q1Component.html:15)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
    at core.js:8154
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:988)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
```

Changing to this code instead works:

```
onShowAllOptions() {
  const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
  const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
  const button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
  const button4 = document.getElementById('button4');
  const showallbutton = document.getElementById('showallbutton');
  button1.classList.toggle('hide');
  button2.classList.toggle('hide');
  button3.classList.toggle('hide');
  button4.classList.toggle('hide');
  showallbutton.classList.add('hide');
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something basic, and I hope you can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend against managing the DOM too much through standard browser methods like `document.getElementById`, etc. Using the Angular abstraction is recommended, you can read more [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

This out of the way, we can get to the *why*.

When the `Skulder14q1Component` is initialized, the DOM (the HTML elements / the template) for it has not been created yet. So when you try to find the buttons, they are not there yet, so `getElementById` returns `null`.

Components in Angular go through a life-cycle, and you can hook into this life-cycle by adding certain methods to your class. you can read more about those in the [docs on lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

In your case, you need the `AfterViewInit` hook. To implement it, we need to do two things:

1. implement the  interface `AfterViewInit`

   ```
   class Skulder14q1Component implements AfterViewInit {
   ...
   }
   ```
2. Add the method

   ```
   class Skulder14q1Component implements AfterViewInit {
       button1: HTMLElement;
       button2: HTMLElement;
       button3: HTMLElement;
       button4: HTMLElement;
       showAllButton: HTMLElement;

       ngAfterViewInit() {
           this.button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
           this.button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
           this.button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
           this.button4 = document.getElementById('button4');
           this.showallbutton = document.getElementById('showallbutton');
       }

       // when this is called later, the buttons will have been set up
       onShowAllOptions() {
           this.button1.classList.toggle('hide');
           this.button2.classList.toggle('hide');
           this.button3.classList.toggle('hide');
           this.button4.classList.toggle('hide');
           this.showallbutton.classList.add('hide');
       }
   }
   ```

The code in the method will run after Angular has prepared the template for you.

---

**Edit**: In my experience, `ViewChild` is not used that often, since you want the elements inside your templates (especially if they are other components) to be responsible for their own behaviour, and not control everything from an omnipotent class.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzh9vh) I made for your use-case precisely.

Comment: Interesting! I'll take a look at angular abstraction. However, how do I call the method on click, if it's placed in ngAfterViewInit() ?

Comment: @ThomasJensen I updated the template with the function. I assume that you had a `(click)` handler in your template, so you can still use that. The life-cycle hook is only there to initialize the properties.

Comment: Wow it works! And your explanation was perfect, thank you!
And what I also got from your message, was that it is better to tap into the lifecycle hooks, instead of manipulating the DOM through the normal methods. Is that correct?

Comment: @ThomasJensen You're welcome. Lifecycle hooks allow you to run your custom functions at certain points of components life. E.g. `onInit` to fetch some data, `onChanges` to update some state. The abstractions over DOM are a completely separate thing. Typically if you want to access an element inside you component's template, you would use `ViewChild` on a property to let angular initialize it for you at the right time.

Comment: Perfect, ViewChild might be just what I need. Thank you again!

Comment: @ThomasJensen I have added a stackblitz link for you, to show that you don't necessarily need a `ViewChild`.

Comment: wow that is a really clean and easy to understand way of doing it. Thank you!